# How does [Authorize] know if the user is logged in or not

Tags: c#, authorization

I am starting to learn about authorized access to my controller actions. My question is if I decorate my controller action with [Authorize] how does the framework know whether the user is logged in or not (that's what I have seen on youtube what [Authorize] does)

```
[Authorize]
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<AccountResponse>> GetAll()
        {
            var accounts = _accountService.GetAll();
            return Ok(accounts);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you configured Authentication in your `Startup.cs`, e.g.:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        options => builder.Configuration.Bind("JwtSettings", options));
```

In this case the JWT in authorization header of the request will be evaluated and checked according to the configured options. But you can also configure a cookie authentication.

You can find further information in the microsoft docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?source=recommendations&view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Do I have to do anything in the code for e.g. cookies - or it is handled for me by the framework?

Comment: You have to configure it in the Startup.cs. The rest is done by the framework.